# i want to add some info in my entry widget in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to add account codes and there values in entry widget or any other widget but I don't know how to do that
following is the info:

{100 : 'Cash',101 : 'Equipments', 102 : 'Supplies' , 103 : 'AccRec' , 104 : 'PreInsurance',
                   200 : 'AccPayable', 201 : 'NotesPay', 202 : 'InterestPayable', 203 : 'AccDepreciation' , 204 : 'Salaries and wages payable',
                   300 : 'Owner_Capital', 301 : 'Owner Drawing',
                   400 : 'Service Revenue' , 401 : 'Rent Revenue',
                   500 : 'Salaries and wages Expense' , 501 : 'Utilities Expense' , 502 : 'Rent Expense' , 503 : "Insurance Expense" , 504 : 'Depreciation Expense' , 505 : 'Supplies expense' }

so that when user wants to insert the account he can know the account code for the value he wants to insert

Comment: show code and full error message.

Comment: there is no error it works fine when I add the account code in the account title entry it will update the value in the database

Comment: i just want to give my user this particular piece of info that he will have to use these following codes for inserting the values

Comment: so what is the problem ? Just display it using Label or Text or create Listbox or OptionMenu to select from list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to list the codes and the respective values inside the GUI window, you can do something like the following

```py
import tkinter as tk

codes = {100 : 'Cash',
        101 : 'Equipments',
        102 : 'Supplies',
        103 : 'AccRec',
        104 : 'PreInsurance',
        200 : 'AccPayable',
        201 : 'NotesPay',
        202 : 'InterestPayable',
        203 : 'AccDepreciation' ,
        204 : 'Salaries and wages payable',
        300 : 'Owner_Capital',
        301 : 'Owner Drawing',
        400 : 'Service Revenue',
        401 : 'Rent Revenue',
        500 : 'Salaries and wages Expense',
        501 : 'Utilities Expense',
        502 : 'Rent Expense',
        503 : "Insurance Expense" ,
        504 : 'Depreciation Expense',
        505 : 'Supplies expense' }

window = tk.Tk()

_row = 0 
for code, value in codes.items():
    tk.Label(window, text=str(code)+' - '+value).grid(row=_row, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
    _row += 1

window.mainloop()
```

[image: cl]

Comment: yeap i think that will work

Comment: I hope this solution helps you. Please accept the answer if you think it solves your problem. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. It will help the community at large to recognize the correct solution. Cheers.